# MySQL Restore from a Simulated Delete

Tags: mysql, database

I have two backups created via [mysqlhotcopy](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqlhotcopy.html):

1. `backup-before-deletion` from August 7, 2014 and
2. `backup-after-deletion` from February 3, 2016

The actual deletion event occurred on July 17, 2015.

So inserts, edits and deletes have to be considered.

The good news is the deletion can be simulated but it would have to be done on the `backup-before-deletion`.

What is the most cost effective way (paid for tools are on the table) to restore the deleted data?